# c# cache not persisting between users

Tags: c#, .net, caching, webforms

I'm experiencing some problems with the use of `System.Web.Caching.Cache`.

Basically I'm using

```
Cache.Insert(tablename, newlist, null, 
   System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, 
   System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

to insert objects into the cache, and `Cache[tablename]` to retrieve them on a webform.

What I'm experiencing is that if I refresh the browser that calls these methods, then the data is there, and Cache.Count reflects this.
However, if I close the browser and start it up again, or start a different browser on my test machine or another, then the Cached data is not there.

Ie the Cache is working as if I was using the Session Store. I've also tried using the Application store too, but with exactly the same results.

I've had a look through my application pool settings and web.config, and can't see anything obvious.

Any help with this would be much appreciated, as requerying the databases to get the information to put in the cache would slow down the webform a great deal.

I'm not sure I'm being clear enough.
To reproduce.
browser 1 opens webpage, no cached data
browser 1 refreshes webpage, cached data

browser 2 opens webpage, no cached data
browser 2 refreshes webpage, cached data

browser 1 refreshes webpage, cached data

So as you can see, it's working exactly as if it was session only data, not a common cache. Using the callback probably wouldn't tell me anything, as the data is still there, just not available to a fresh session

Comment: try adding a callback handler for when items are removed from cache and see when it fires?

Comment: this is still not working for me

Comment: Have you tried putting a simple web application together to recreate the problem. 
I have just tried this and works as expected... as long as my DelvelopementServer was "alive" the cache was still populated

Comment: take a look here, if you havent already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421744/httpcontext-current-cache-item-null-after-page-refresh

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you restart the application by pressing F5 in Visual Studio.

Just open a new browser Window without restarting the application.

Comment: I'm not doing anything in visual studio between tests, just starting a new browser session, and the data is gone