# Why i have to put my object twice in HttpContext Cache before it keep it for good?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, caching, httpcontext.cache

When i cache an object to the `HttpContext Cache`, my object disappear on the next read and I must reinsert the object a second time (not always but 90% of the time). After that, the object stay there without any problem.

Here's what happen:

1. Start debugging the mvc project
2. Read the age from the cache
3. The **age is null** so i put 50 in the variable and then insert it in the cache
4. The `CacheItemRemovedCallback` gets executed immediately when the response to the client is done. The `CacheItemRemovedReason` value is `Removed`
5. The user click refresh immediately
6. Read the age from the cache
7. The **age is still null** so i put 50 in the variable and then insert it in the cache
8. The user click refresh immediately
9. Read the age from the cache
10. The **age is there finally**!

So why the `Cache` have this problem to keep the object in cache on the first insert?

This behavior exist in the `.Net framework 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.2`.

Here's the code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        int? age = this.HttpContext.Cache.Get("age") as int?;
        if (age == null)
        {
            age = 50;

            this.HttpContext.Cache.Add("age", age, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(5), TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority.Default, new CacheItemRemovedCallback(this.CacheItemRemovedCallback));
        }
        return View();
    }

    public void CacheItemRemovedCallback(String key, Object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you arent specifying a cache duration in the Insert()? The item may be getting scavenged sooner than you think.

Comment: Because this is not required to do so and since that the second time the object is cached for good, i understand that whithout specifying the cache duration, the default is to keep the object infinitly.

Comment: Cache is never permanent. Infinity is not the default and cache will have items removed if they are deemed no longer needed. Supply a time of 1 hour for the cache and you should see the item the first time you expect it.

Comment: sure you dont have a race condition?

Comment: For reference [httpcontext-current-cache-item-null-after-page-refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421744/httpcontext-current-cache-item-null-after-page-refresh)

Comment: ***I cannot replicate the issue*** in all browsers - IE, FF and Chrome. Could you upload the sample project somewhere?

Comment: I have updated the description. I have added the CacheItemRemovedCallback function and it gets executed immediately when i insert the value for the first time.

Comment: I've just tested the same code at home and I cannot reproduce the problem. Pretty weird. Is there a way to listen to some other events of the application to know why my object gets removed from the cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why my cached item was removed immediately after his insertion was because the **AppDomain get unloaded** after the first call to the website. By catching the unload event of the `AppDomain`, i've been able to know the shutdown reason. The **antivirus** was scanning a file of the website that triggered the `FileChangesMonitor` event of the `AppDomain` that then triggered the **unload of the AppDomain**.

Here's how to detect the reason why the AppDomain get unloaded :

**Global.asax**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.DomainUnload += DomainUnloadEventHandler;
    }

    static void DomainUnloadEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var httpRuntimeType = typeof(HttpRuntime);

        var httpRuntime = httpRuntimeType.InvokeMember(
            "_theRuntime",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField,
            null, null, null) as HttpRuntime;

        var shutDownMessage = httpRuntimeType.InvokeMember(
            "_shutDownMessage",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField,
            null, httpRuntime, null) as string;

        string shutDownStack = httpRuntime.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "_shutDownStack",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField,
            null, httpRuntime, null) as string;
    }
}
```

Here's what the `shutDownMessage` variable contains:

```
_shutDownMessage: Change Notification for critical directories.
bin dir change or directory rename
HostingEnvironment initiated shutdown
HostingEnvironment caused shutdown
Change in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\48a6542f\e317ebf6\hash\hash.web
```

Has you can see, the **hash.web** file is the cause of the AppDomain unload. Now, who is altering this file? It turns out to be the antivirus. By **deactivating the On-Access scanner of McAfee**, the hash.web file was not altered anymore so no AppDomain unload. Problem solved!

For further information, you can read this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/05/14/asp-net-performance-issue-large-number-of-application-restarts-due-to-virus-scanning.aspx).